# Can't Add Ml backend in label-studio

Tags: python, machine-learning

I am trying to add my ML model on label studio.
I have tried these commands

```
cd label-studio
pip install -e .
cd label_studio/ml/examples
pip install -r requirements.txt


   label-studio-ml init my_ml_backend --script label_studio/ml/examples/simple_text_classifier.py
```

These are the files in label_studio/ml/examples:-
requirements.txt

```
simple_text_classifier.py

dummy_model.py

pytorch_transfer_learning.py
```

It's giving me this error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'simple_text_classifier'
```

How can I add my model on label studio?

Comment: Plese read the description of the [tag:ml] tag.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Probably a little late, but maybe someone else finds this question. What did the trick for me: while in the `label_studio/ml/examples` folder, try

```
label-studio-ml init my_ml_backend --script simple_text_classifier.py
```

(I simply removed the rest of the parth from the script)
If you get an error telling you to add `--force`, do either that (which will override the existing `my_ml_backend` folder) or simply delete the `my_ml_backend` folder and run the same command again.

After that, you hopefully should get the following response:

```
Congratulations! ML Backend has been successfully initialized in ./my_ml_backend
Now start it by using:
label-studio-ml start ./my_ml_backend
```

Comment: https://github.com/heartexlabs/label-studio-ml-backend full guide

Answer (score 1):

The quick solution that worked for me is that I navigated (`cd`) to the directory containing `simple_text_classifier.py` i.e. `examples`, and then from that directory executed the command:

`label-studio-ml init my_ml_backend --script simple_text_classifier.py`